# REGEXP bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to delete first four letters in 'OLD_DATA'column contains following data- (with delete all data in front of ":") and keep remaining data.

```
-----------------------                 ----------------------- 
     OLD_DATA (before)                        NEW_DATA(after)
----------------------                  ----------------------
abc:cdef-12E456-AB                          cdef-12E456-AB
cdef-12E456-AB-12E456-AB                    cdef-12E456-AB
bcd:ghij-12E456-BS                          ghij-12E456-BS
abc:cdef-12E456-AB                          cdef-12E456-AB
cdef-12E456-AB                              cdef-12E456-AB
ghij-12E456-BS                              ghij-12E456-BS
bcd:ghij-12E456-BS                          ghij-12E456-BS
cdef-12E456-AB                              cdef-12E456-AB
abc:cdef-12E456-AB                          cdef-12E456-AB
abc:cdef-12E456-AB                          cdef-12E456-AB
-------------------------               -------------------------
```

I wrote following code: REGEXP_EXTRACT(`TABLE`.OLD_DATA,r'(\w*):') as NEW_DATA: as expected separated first three letters in to separate column but not deleting from actual data.

This code : REGEXP_EXTRACT(`TABLE`.OLD_DATA,r':(\w*)') as NEW_DATA
separating values in between ":" and first"-" ....which are 5 to 10 letters.

Any suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(old_data, r'^\w*:', '') as new_data
FROM table
```

Comment: is it possible to get rid of any "empty" , "NULL" ,"0" and "1"  values in this OLD_DATA column...?

Comment: give an example

Comment: Actual old data table with no data or null  or 1 or 0 data   .sorry format seems wrong when types as comment                                                   "HPLA-19C204-BB  
GX63-14C151-AC  
FW93-19C204-BG  

JPLA-19C204-BB
HPLA-19C204-BA  
null
1
HPLA-19C204-BF  
0
JX63-19C204-BB  
null
GX63-19C204-BB 
HPLA-19C204-BE  
JPLA-19C204-BA"

Comment: add something like `WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(old_data, r'.*-.*-.*')` to the end of query

Comment: great. when you will have enough reputation on SO - come back and what it up :o)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.   This comes to mind:

```
select regexp_replace(data, '^...:', '')
```

Note that this answers your *question*, but it does not produce the desired output because the two are not in sync.